# Canonical LivePatch on ARM64

Tags: canonical-livepatch, arm64

I have Ubuntu 20.04 **64 bit** on Raspberry Pi 4. 
The CPU architecture is **ARM64**. 
Can I use Canonical LivePatch easily somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are patches but it's not ready yet. 
It seems like it will take a few years: 
https://www.spinics.net/lists/live-patching/msg06039.html
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=ARM64-Linux-Live-Kernel-Patch

Answer (score 2):

**No.**

The [Livepatch Datasheet](https://assets.ubuntu.com/v1/ef19ede0-Datasheet_Livepatch_AW_Web_30.07.18.pdf) is conspicuous and clear on this topic:

> Architecture: 64-bit (x86_64 or amd64)

ARM64 is not supported by Livepatch.

Comment: I asked because of this https://github.com/sirmordred/livepatch-for-arm64/commit/6b088bd78c47c514485ce50d21fd2be5db7c2a5b